# How do I unscribe to this for I never signed up for this?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

This is not my pet's question but my pet peeve. Never ever ever signed up for this website and never heard of it until I got an email this morning. So how did you get my personal email address? I know you bought it from a company that I do business with like Amazon. Well, it will stop or I will sue for harassment. Simple just get rid of my address.

Comment: What sort of email did you recieve?

Comment: @AshleyNunn - Account history shows the initial account verification. Email address likely came through the Facebook authorization, it would be common to get basic information in this way and the user would have to authorize it on Facebook.

Comment: Your account is scheduled for deletion. As a recommendation for the future, when you log into a service, such as this one, using Facebook then you're telling Facebook to provide basic personal details which includes your email. The message that this site sent was to make sure that *you* were the one that logged in via Facebook. I would moderate the hostile reaction, you approved it and it's something to remember the next time you log into a service using Facebook.

Answer (score 6):

The email you received was the account confirmation email based on your own actions to actually create the account, including clicking through the initial legal information and signing in with Facebook. I will remove your account at your request, but I don't think the threats are really necessary...